# Show an AlertView, do parsing and dismiss AlertView - with GCD

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I m very new to iOS, as stated in the question above; im trying to do these 3 simple step.

1. Show Alert view
2. Do parsing stuff
3. Dismiss Alert

I was looking for something like we have in android i.e Pre Execute, doInBackground and Post Execute().

This is what i have tried.

```
parserAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Loading" message:@"Please Wait"    delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

[parserAlert show];

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.abc.testing",  DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

dispatch_sync(queue,^{
   DBHandler *myDB= [[DBHandler alloc] init];
   [myDB fetchResults];
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
         [parserAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];

   });

});
```

Below is the fetchResult method.

```
- (void) fetchResults
{

 IParser *i = [[IParser alloc] init];
 [i startParse];


 AGParser *ag = [[AGParser alloc] init];
 [ag startParse];


 GParser *g = [[GParser alloc] init];
 [g startParse];

 HParser *h = [[HParser alloc] init];
 [h startParse];

 SParser *s = [[SParser alloc] init];
 [s startParse];


}
```

This is startParse.

```
NSString *url = @"http://abcd.com/Service_URL/Service.asmx/GetNotes";

NSURL *nsUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:url];
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:nsUrl];

NSURLConnection *con = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

[con start];
```

When i run the above code, Alerview show and dismiss within a second. Adding logs on methods i observed that fetchresults method return immediately and alert view gets dismiss. However fetchResults associated threads(Connection methods, Parser methods) keep executing but alerview is dismissed.

I need a guideline how to block the code until all associated methods are finished.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: A lot depends on what `startParse` does! Maybe you could share some of that? (For example, you say "connection" - but that might be asynchronous.)

Comment: @matt, i have added the code of startParse method.

Comment: Yes, it's just as I thought. `[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self]` returns *immediately*; the networking is in yet another background thread. I'll add that to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is not the answer you want, but don't use an alert view for this. A nice way to cover for time-consuming activity to is to put up a UIActivityIndicatorView, or a view that contains one, and set it spinning:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch25.html#_uiactivityindicatorview

You can also prevent user interaction while the time-consuming activity is happening, with the shared application object's `beginIgnoring...` (and turn that off with `endIgnoring...` when you're done). Obviously you can't do that, though, if the user is to be given a Cancel button. In that case, cover everything else with an invisible view (clear background color) whose `userInteractionEnabled` is YES, so that it eats any touches intended for anything other than the button.

Also, it is almost *never* the right answer to use `dispatch_sync`. Once you've frozen the interface in the way I've just described, you can just do your connections (asynchronous) and parsing (on a background thread) and then come back into the main thread to dismiss the activity indicator.

Finally, you're going to want to leave yourself a way out in case things go wrong. You could run an NSTimer, for example.

EDIT: And now for the actual answer to your actual question, i.e. why is my code not pausing even though I used `dispatch_sync`: it's because `[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self]` returns immediately; the networking is in yet another background thread. So your `startParse` returns, your `fetchResults` returns, and meanwhile the networking continues and the NSURLConnection delegate methods are called some time later.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How can i tell background thread is finished, because as u said NSURLConnection are called some time later.

Comment: Since you are already in a background thread, you are allowed to use `sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:`.

Comment: Thanks, i will check that.. will get back to you.

Comment: I am not saying I think `sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:` is the best way. But the whole question of what *is* the best way is a separate issue (and you might want to ask it as a separate question). I believe I have answered the question you *did* ask, namely, why the alert view was being dismissed while the connect-and-parse code was still running.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [the link](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) what you are looking for `MBProgressHUD`
First alloc the MBProgressHUD instance of it in the `viewDidLoad`

```
MBProgressHUD *progressHUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
progress.delegate=self;
[progressHUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(performBackgroundTask) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES]
```

and in the background method

```
-(void)performBackgroundTask
{
    //Do some stuff
}
```

and soon as the task in the )performBackgroundTaskmethod is completed the Activity indicator shown in the `MBProgressHUD` will hidden and the delegate method called

```
-(void)hudWasHidden
{ 
   //Do additional stuff after completion of background task 
}
```

Hope it will help you.